# Handle paytm CallBack URL response inside android App

Tags: java, android, spring-boot, paytm

I integrated the android paytm integration using below dependency,'com.paytm:pgplussdk:1.3.3' It is working fine in my android app. But after successful transaction, it is redirecting to callback url which i specified using spring boot it return success response to my app in new page. It is not coming back to app itself. when i click on back options it shows 'cancel transaction' dialog box even my transaction is successful. how can i handle this scenario please suggest me better way.

```
HashMap<String, String> paytmParamMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
Iterator<String> iter = response.keys();
while (iter.hasNext()){
    String key = iter.next();
    paytmParamMap.put(key, response.getString(key));
}                          
final PaytmPGService paytmPGService = PaytmPGService.getStagingService();                          
PaytmOrder paytmOrder = new PaytmOrder(paytmParamMap);
paytmPGService.initialize(paytmOrder, null);
                               paytmPGService.startPaymentTransaction(getActivity(), true, true, new PaytmPaymentTransactionCallback() {

@Override
public void onTransactionResponse(Bundle inResponse) {
    Log.d("PaymentTransactionRes", inResponse.toString());
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Payment Transaction response " + inResponse.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

After getting response from callbackUrl, onclick back option how to redirect back to application without showing any dialog box.

Comment: Have you got any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Send the Payment gateway to another Activity from onTransactionResponse

```
public void onTransactionResponse(Bundle inResponse) {

                    Log.e("server response", ""+inResponse);
                    String status = inResponse.getString("STATUS");
                    String transactionid = inResponse.getString("TXNID");
                    String amount = inResponse.getString("TXNAMOUNT");
                    if(status!=null)
                    {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TargetActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("transactionid",transactionid);
                        intent.putExtra("amount",amount);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       // print log 
                    }

                }
```